# How to retrieve an image from a post and display it before excerpt of a post?

Tags: theme-development, loop, templates, customization, development-strategy

I'm customizing a WordPress template and I would implement the following behavior in the excerpt posts visualization in my homepage:

**If a post contains images (one or more), in the homepage post preview show at the begining a thumbnail of the first image that is in the post, then show the excerpt of the post.**

At the moment I have the following code that, inside a WordPress loop, show the excerpts of all posts in homepage:

```
<!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'admired' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div>
```

As you can see this code snippet show the excerpt of a post.

Is it possible to find the first image in the post, put it into a variable and show it inside a span (or some other HTML tag) before the excerpt visualization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is the "Featured Image" of your post, you can use:

```
<?php 
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } 
?>
```

check: [the_post_thumbnail function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

else if you want to get the first image inside your post, you can use somthing like that:

```
function get_first_post_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  //Defines a default image
  if(empty($first_img)){ 
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Then place `<?php echo get_first_post_image(); ?>`

Comment: ok, maybe I am loosing something. From what I understand I can use the "Featured Image" of my post without using extra function...but what is it this "Featured Image"? how can I set it in my posts?

Comment: ok, solved: the I can set the "Featured Image" when I create or I modify an article !!! Perfetct !!!TNX